# Applications running with Docker destroy external mariadb connections after a while

Tags: docker, jar, mariadb

I have an application made with spring boot.

I created this application directly as a service and deployed it with systemd, and there were no problems.

Additionally, the database is installed directly on the server.

Now, we have packaged and deployed the Spring boot application with docker.

There are no problems with execution, and there is no problem with communication.

However, if there are no requests for about 5 minutes, all connections in mariadb are destroyed.

When you send a request at this time, the server displays a log indicating that the connection has been lost.

Afterwards, when I check mariadb, a new connection has been created and there is no problem with the request.

All options were set the same. What on earth is this problem?

```
2023-11-20T16:28:42.554+09:00  WARN 34 --- [http-nio-9000-exec-4] c.z.h.p.PoolBase                         : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection org.mariadb.jdbc.Connection@7df7b0ab ((conn=93924) Connection.setNetworkTimeout cannot be called on a closed connection). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
```

The same 10 lines of code above occur. (matches my connection full size)

#### Notes

The photo below is the result when I checked after starting the service, waited a while, and checked again.

When I send the request again, 10 new connections are created like the first one. (After an error occurred on the server)

mariadb `wait_timeout` and Hikariful `maxLifetime` were all set to default settings and were not touched, and we confirmed that they were the same as the default settings.

[image]